# Why does ntdll.dll export NtXXX and ZwXXX rather than NtXXX only?

Tags: c, windows, api, function, dll

As we know:

1. ntdll.dll exports two versions of native APIs: `NtXXX` and `ZwXXX`.
2. In user mode, an `NtXXX` is identical to its corresponding `ZwXXX`.
3. The MSDN says: Use `NtXXX` only if you are in user mode.

I just wonder:

Why does ntdll.dll export `NtXXX` and `ZwXXX` rather than `NtXXX` only?

Comment: Do you mean ntdll.dll can set `PreviousMode` to `KernelMode` ever before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It allows user-mode programs to use code snippets written for kernel mode (with the `Zw` API), if those particular snippets don't actually use kernel privilege.

Comment: This is a convincing rationale. Best Answer!